# Silverlight 4 value getting set but "wrong" value is being retrieved

Tags: silverlight-4.0, ria

I have got the following scenario. In my SL application, I am getting some data using RIA. ON the first load of the application, the data gets pulled out correctly and I bind the data to the front end.

Then I change some filter parameters and only one field in the data returned changes. I've traced it and it's definitely not a problem with my query which in fact returns the right data. So, I've put some breakpoint on the DomainService class generated. The data is set correctly as shown here:

[image: Set value of 285.8333]

However, when it comes to getting the data back out, it is pulling out the data on the first page load as shown here:

[image: Get value of 215.83333]

Can anyone advise as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what's going on without some idea of the rest of the code. For example, is it possible you are looking at the wrong record? Alternatively, are you handling an event that cancels the change? Can you give an indication of what filter parameters you are changing?

Comment: Hi Dave, yes I do agree that it's kind of hard and I'll try to provide as much detail as possible. I am for sure not looking at the wrong record and that can't be it since the value set and value returned are not the same. I am not handling any event at all. It's pretty much a "vanilla" operation i.e. call the data and bind to controls. The filter parameters I am changing are dates i.e. start and end date for an operation. In the db the work hours available is being calculated based on those dates and is the only value that changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out how to fix it although I really don't know why things behave the way they do.

So some more background on the operation I'm carrying out. With the data and the filters I've chosen, assume that I consistently get three rows of data. The only difference when I change the filter parameters i.e. start date or end date, is that the workHoursAvailable values change but these changes for some reason don't get reflected when I call the web service method.

To "solve" the issue what I did was this. I hacked the unique id identifying each and ensured that for the same rows of data, the unique ids would change after changing the filters. When that happened, the correct workHoursAvailable would be called from my web service method.

I don't even want to speculate at what is going on in the background but if anyone reading this knows then please do leave an explanation.

---

After further investigation I found this

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/120834/462505.aspx

and effectively I had to clear my domain context e.g.
DomainContext.EntityContainer.Clear();